# Form control-group for rails polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have following models:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :bookable, polymorphic: true
end

class Student < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :books, as: :bookable
end

class Library < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, as: :bookable
end
```

When creating a new book object in form.html.erb, how I could map  t.integer :bookable_id and t.string :bookable_type to specific object?

Ideally I would use grouped_collection_select and pull first Student and Library and below their ids.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> When creating a new book object in form.html.erb, how I could map
>   t.integer :bookable_id and t.string :bookable_type to specific object?

Well, you can use the `collection_select` or `grouped_collection_select` (according to your requirements) to display `Students` and `Libraries` to store the values for `bookable_id`.

For `bookable_type`, Rails under the hood reads the class names of the instances and captures the class name and stores it as a value for `bookable_type`. For example, consider the below approach

```
@student = Student.find(1)
@student.books.create
```

The above code snippet will create a record in `books` table with `bookable_id = 1` and `bookable_type = "Student"`